# For a boost converter does the increase of capacitance values at the output, increase the temperature on the switching MOSFETs?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost

I'm designing TI LM5122 based boost converter. Does the increase of capacitances at the output increase the temperature on the switching MOSFETs?
[LM5122 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5122.pdf?ts=1669862411616&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM5122)

[image]

Comment: How can capacitance grow?

Comment: If I add more parallel capacitance , output capacitance value will be grow,

Comment: "grow" is usually an organic term that implies self-growth (like in a plant). "increase" is the word that is preferred. Anyway, for a constant load, the answer is no.

Comment: ups sorry, ım not a native speaker.I'm correcting.

Comment: It's no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Does the increase of capacitances at the output increase the
> temperature on the switching mosfets?*

No it doesn't except in the first cycles from a power up situation because, it takes longer to raise the bigger value output capacitance to the required regulated output voltage.

After that, for a constant load scenario, it won't make a difference.

This is because the load takes a certain amount of energy per switching cycle and, with more capacitance, it will take the same amount of energy but deplete the capacitance voltage less. Hence, when the boost circuit tops up the capacitor it provides only the energy needed as that taken by the load per cycle.